# How to get the base address of a shared library in LLVM IR?

Tags: linux, llvm, llvm-ir

The image base address of a program can be obtained through a global variable @__executable_start, but how to get the base address of a shared library such as libc.so in LLVM IR?

In other words, how to dump the memory layout of a process by instrumenting?

Thanks in advance!